# Command line switch for GoToMeeting to join a meeting by ID?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, gotomeeting

My colleagues and I have a recurring weekly meeting set up. I'd like to set up a shortcut to that meeting (in Windows 7). I can make a URL shortcut like this

```
https://www2.gotomeeting.com/join/123456789
```

but that fires up a browser window which then has to be closed - it would be cleaner to just call `g2mstart.exe` with a command line argument to join meeting 123456789. I've tried guessing at the syntax to join a specific meeting but haven't found it, and haven't found a guide to command-line switches anywhere online. Clearly `g2mstart.exe` takes arguments - the standard shortcut looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\GoToMeeting\457\g2mstart.exe" 
"/Action Host" "/Trigger Shortcut" "/Product G2M"
```

Is there a guide somewhere to these switches? And is there one that allows joining a specific meeting by ID?

Comment: I'm gonna ask the stupid question here, just to be sure:  Have you tried any of the following:  `g2mstart.exe /?`, `g2mstart.exe -?`, `g2mstart.exe /help`, `g2mstart.exe -help`?

Comment: @Iszi - Thanks, I hadn't tried those, but I did, and none of them do anything.

Comment: Well, it was worth a shot.  Most GUI apps don't bother to put info in those switches anymore, but sometimes you get lucky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it after a little more trial and error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\GoToMeeting\457\g2mstart.exe" 
"/Action Join" "/MeetingID 123456789"
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what Marco Valtas said you can simply create a shortcut on the desktop (or anywhere else) with the URI `gotomeeting://SALaunch?Action=Join&MeetingID=123456789` this works great for me on Windows. No browser or anything, straight into the meeting.

Comment: This works better as it's a bit more future proof. The local path in @herb-caudill answer is no longer used. It's not in Program Files anymore, and the local file path has a version number in it which breaks on updates.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will still have to register (the same way as you would have if you used Join... from menu)

I tried and this works flawlessly: `/UserID 123456789`

Would love to find how this could've been done on a Macintosh

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in OSX the simplest way is to use the URL registred by GoToMeeting application on the LaunchServices which by using `open` you can pass the arguments. After some digging and trimming I could narrow down to this:

```
 open 'gotomeeting://SALaunch?Action=Join&MeetingID=123456789'
```